# Photoshop: Batch Fit Image x Bicublic Sharper?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, resize, batch-processing, photoshop-scripting

1) By `File -> Automate -> Fit Image...`,

we can fit images of any size or orientation into a particular frame size. But we cannot specify the resample method, like `Bicublic Sharper`. In fact we do not know what resample method it uses.

2) By `Image -> Image Size...`,

we can control the resample methods. But for batch processing, like batch resize photos of different orientation, we cannot specify a "fit-frame" size in this menu.

Is there a way/a script/a menu that we can combine the advantages of the two - **Batch Fit** Image with `Bicublic Sharper`?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually take a look at the source of the Fit Image script. It's in `\Presets\Scripts\Fit Image.jsx` (at least for CS5).

In my script, the resampling method is on line 135:

```js
app.activeDocument.resizeImage(newWidth, newHeight, resolution, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
```

So there you go, the default method is **Bicubic**.

According to the reference guide, we can send one of the following:

- `BICUBIC`
- `BICUBICSHARPER`
- `BICUBICSMOOTHER`
- `BILINEAR`
- `NEARESTNEIGHBOR`
- `NONE`

Same as the image size dialog in PS (big surprise!), with an additional NONE.

---

### "Band-aid" Script

I am far from an expert at scripting in Photoshop, but I was able to modify the existing Fit Image script to incorporate a re-sampling method dropdown. This works for me in CS5, I did not test it in any other version of Photoshop.

#### Old Script:

[image: Old 'n' Busted]

#### New Script:

[image: New Hotness]

[**Get it here**](https://github.com/johnballantyne/FitImagePlus)

**Edit:** <s>Okay, so this isn't (yet) compatible with a recorded action, which admittedly makes it kinda worthless. I'll have to figure out how that works.</s> Now with recorded action functionality!

Comment: Thanks. But i am using the CS2 version. There is no `Fit Image.jsx` in my `Scripts` folder, `Event Scripts Only` folder neither. If, as quoted in your code, `ResampleMethod.BICUBIC` is hard-coded into the `Fit Image` command, i wonder why after i changed my Preferences, the resample method follows?

Comment: @midnite Interesting, I'm on CS5. I don't have CS2, so I'm not sure how it's set up there.

Comment: @midnite, I've put the script on GitHub. Try it out and see if it works for you on CS2

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and information. Hmm... may i ask, (1) if you set `Bicubic Sharper` in the CS5 Preferences, then do the original `Fit Image`, will the output be using `Bicubic Sharper`? (You may test the output files with their file sizes. Same resized images, with same resampling method, should have the same file size.)

Comment: Cont'd, (2) My CS2 `Fit Image` is at the `File > Automate > Fit Image...`. CS2 doesn't have `Fit Image` in `File > Scripts > `. Where is the CS5 `Fit Image`?

Comment: @midnite, it looks like PS scripting got a massive re-vamp in CS3. I gave it a quick shot in CS2, but everything is drastically different. It'd be easier to re-write the script from the ground up. The CS2 Fit Image script is located at `\Plug-Ins\Adobe Photoshop Only\Automate\Fit Image.8LI`. I do not know how to edit an 8LI file, otherwise I'd give modifying that one a shot.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solution to this.

### 1. Write a script.

Because of this issue, i have just started reading the [manuals](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html). i am the programming guy. But Photoshop does contain many classes, and coding JavaScript in plain text editor is not easy. And, more importantly, i found method 2 is working!

### 2. Through native Photoshop Preferences.

i may need to write a script for more complex operations. But not today. Simply open Photoshop, go to `Edit > Preferences > General > Image Interpolation` and choose `Bicubic Sharper`. i have tested this works well with `File > Automate > Fit Image...` and `File > Scripts > Image Processor...`, which means both will use `Bicubic Sharper` for resampling :)

P.S. i chose to build my own `Action` with `Fit Image` because i feel more safe with this. `Image Processor` is a bunch of codes, which *may* contain bugs, or *may* choose resampling methods other than `Bicubic Sharper`, somehow, in some cases, who knows?

Comment: notepad++ is free open source and has syntax highlighting for javascript. A step up from vanilla notepad.exe

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @horatio :) i use Notepad++ also. i am just lazy to check out all the new Photoshop APIs :P